# Integration test on a library using UI Tests or unit testing framework?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, integration-testing, xcode-ui-testing

There is an iOS library (SDK) that I have to write integration tests for. This library is being used in iOS client apps as a library, never as a standalone app.

I have found 2 equally good opinions on how I shall approach to writing integration tests.

1. Use XCode UI test and test end-to-end integration of a library withing a sample client app. The client app will be using all features of the library. This way UI test can show me how the library integrates with a client app.
2. Use unit testing framework. The tests would be written inside the library itself. There is no need for a client app at all. The tests will be run against multiple classes to see how they integrate between themselves.

What do you propose as the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

UI tests are slow to run and expensive (in terms of time) to maintain. They should only be used as a way to get test coverage when it isn't possible to get it in other ways that are faster to run and easier to maintain.

If your library doesn't have a UI of any kind then there is no reason to introduce one just to run UI tests. It would make more sense to use option 2 as described above.

The only caveat to that would be that example client apps can be very helpful for manual testing while making changes or regression testing after making changes. The value of this would depend on what is in your library. If you do make an example app then it can be a good idea to write one or two UI tests just to check that it doesn't regress/break when you make changes. This is especially valuable if you don't use it very often.